# A star algorithm in c++

Tags: c++, priority-queue, path-finding, a-star

I am trying to implement A* search algorithm with priority_queues and I have drawn the output on the console with opengl.

I got this output: [Final path with A star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rbCZ.jpg)

Where the cells in gray weren't visited, in yellow were visited and the final path in blue.

I think that the cells that were visited should be less and closer to the path, or I am wrong?

I computed the path with the following code:

```
list<Node*> compute_path_A_star(Node* start, Node* goal)
{
    priority_queue< nodeDistance, vector< nodeDistance >, CompareDist> pq;
    vector<Node*> came_from;
    vector<float> cost_so_far; 

    nodeDistance first;
    first.node = start;
    first.distance = 0.0f;
    pq.push(first);

    came_from.resize(20 * 20, nullptr);

    cost_so_far.resize(20 * 20, 9999.0f); 
    cost_so_far[start->x + 20 * start->y] = 0.0f;

    //Compute where we came from for every location that’s visited
    int i = 0;
    while (!pq.empty())
    {
        nodeDistance temp = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        Node* current_node = temp.node;
        current_node = get_node(current_node->x, current_node->y);

        if (current_node == goal) break;

        for (auto n : current_node->neighbours)
        {
            float new_cost = cost_so_far[current_node->x + 20 * current_node->y] + n->cost;

            if (new_cost < cost_so_far[n->x + 20 * n->y])
            {
                cost_so_far[n->x + 20 * n->y] = new_cost;
                came_from[n->x + 20 * n->y] = current_node;

                nodeDistance newNode;
                newNode.node = n;
                newNode.distance = new_cost + heuristic(n, goal);
                pq.push(newNode);

            }
        }
    }



    #pragma region Create the path (start -> goal)

        Node* current = new Node();
        current = goal;
        list<Node*> path;
        path.push_back(current);
        while (current != start)
        {
            current = came_from[current->x + 20 * current->y];

            path.push_back(current);
        }
        path.reverse();

    #pragma endregion

    return path;
}
```

I used Manhattan distance for the heuristic:

```
float heuristic(Node* a, Node* b)
{
    //Manhattan distance on a square grid
    return (abs(a->x - b->x) + abs(a->y - b->y));
}
```

nodeDistance is a struct:

```
struct nodeDistance
{
    Node* node;
    float distance;
};
```

And for the comparision in the priority queue I defined this class:

```
class CompareDist
{
public:
    bool operator()(nodeDistance& n1, nodeDistance& n2)
    {
        if (n1.distance > n2.distance)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

I defined each node as:

```
struct Node
{
    int x, y;
    float cost;
    Node* parent;
    list<Node*> neighbours;
};
```

And the graph:

```
list<Node*> Graph;
```

Edit 1:

For the A star implementation, I was based on this page http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html.

There is something that I missed? Thanks!

Edit 2:

I have inserted some obstacles (dark-gray cells) and waypoints (pink cells) on the scene. In red the goal cell

[image]

Comment: I'd want to see a clearer failure mode. A star doesn't provide strong guarantees about performance, However it does appear that the heuristic hasn't been highly weighted. A test on an empty map isn't really fair, however, that's not what it's designed for.

Comment: Yes, that's true, I will update a picture with obstacles and waypoints

Comment: Why are you weighting the y cost 20 times the x?

Comment: @Gene I'm fairly certain you're correct. ladymac, look closely at line 15: `start->x + 20 * start->y`. The lines beforehand do this: `.resize(20 * 20, ____)`